# Static analysis for Python functional programming best practices?

Tags: python

Is there static analysis tool which checks Python 3 code for functional programming best practices, pure functions, etc.?

EDIT: Moved to [softwarerecs.stackexchange.com](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/52409/static-analysis-for-python-functional-programming-best-practices)

Comment: If your question would be closed as offtopic, you might try https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com .

Comment: Ouh, you could be right. Thanks for the hint!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question, if asked with more precise specifications, may be on-topic for [Software Recommendations Stack Exchange](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Move is resonable. But I cannot think of how to ask more precisely?

Answer (score 1):

Sonarqube has a [Python](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/SonarPython) plugin.

Comment: SonarCube has no FP (functional programming) specific analysis. Custom checks can be added but I am searching a standalone tool.